# Product of the elements in Galois group and irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Statement) Let $K$ be a Galois extension over a field $F \ \text{s.t.} \ \vert G(K/F) \vert =[K;F] =n $

Say $ G(K/F)  = \{ \sigma_1(=id) , \sigma_2,..., \sigma_n  \}$

Take a element of $\alpha \in K \setminus F$, whose $deg(irr(\alpha, F))= n $

Then $\text{irr}(\alpha,F) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$

---

In my guess, the above statement is true. Considering the properties of the Galois group, Because the $\forall \sigma_i$ which are the elements of the $G(K/F)$, $\alpha$ and $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ are conjugates sharing the same irreducible polynomials.

Is my thought right?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$
You are right.

Let $G$ be the Galois group of $K:F$.
For any $\alpha\in K$,define
$$
  p_\alpha(x)=\prod_{\beta\in O_\alpha}(x-\beta)
$$
where $O_\alpha$ is the $G$-orbit of $\alpha$.

**Claim.** Then for all $\alpha\in K$, $p_\alpha(x)$ lies in $F[x]$ and is irreducible over $F$.

**Proof.**
Let $\alpha\in K$.
The coefficients of $p_\alpha(x)$ are fixed by each member of $G$ and are thus in the fixed field of $G$, which is $F$.
To prove irreducibility of $p_\alpha(x)$ over $F$, assume on the contrary that $p_\alpha(x)$ is reducible over $F$.
Thus there exists a proper subset $O$ of $O_\alpha$ such that $p(x):=\prod_{\beta\in O}(x-\beta)$ lies in $F[x]$.
But then $p(x)$ is fixed by each member of $G$, and consequently we have $\sigma(\beta)\in O$ for all $\beta\in O$.
But this would mean that the $G$-orbit of an element of $O$ is not $O_\alpha$, which is a contradiction.

So we see that the degree of the minimal polynomial of any $\alpha\in K$ is same as the the size of the $G$-orbit of $\alpha$. So if $\deg(\text{irr}(\alpha, F)) = n= |G|$, we must have that the orbit of $\alpha$ has size $n$ and consequently the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is
$$
\prod_{\sigma\in G} (x-\sigma(\alpha))
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I missed the  condition that "degree of the irreducible polynomial is $n$" in my post. I revised my post. Would you check one more time?

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I have edited my answer.

Comment: Dear @caffeinemachine, Awesome proof! :) Thank you for checking my question again.